# try to use DBT unload_table macro with syntax error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, dbt

I want to `UNLOAD` a Redshift table into S3.

The query below has the same format as dbt lab shows on their website, and I’m sure that the s3 path, key and secret are correct. However, after I run the query it shows a syntax error at line 13.

```
{{
  config(
      {
        "materialized":"table",
        "post-hook": [
            "{{ redshift.unload_table(
                this.dbt_test_ods,
                this.user_performance,
                s3_path = 's3://XXXX/user_performance/',
                aws_key = ‘XXXX',
                aws_secret = ‘XXXX',
                format = 'parquet',
                parallel = False
                ) }}"
            ]
        }
    )
}}
```

Comment: Please add the _exact_ error message to your Question. Does it give any indication of which line is "line 13"? This Answer might be useful: [dbt redshift unload_table macro database issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70468164/174777)

Comment: Also providing the compiled SQL would help :)

Comment: Hi John & Aleix
Thank you for responce!!! appreciated!
https://github.com/dbt-labs/redshift/blob/main/macros/unload.sql
the link above is compile UNLOAD statement
and the error detail was just like a syntax error although I fellow all of macro format that shows on the official dbt labs website.
ERROR CONTEXT:
07:57:50  Postgres adapter: Postgres error: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 13:   );
           ^

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.